# Jekyll config.yml Error: did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection

Tags: yaml, syntax-error, jekyll

The command line is showing me the following error in the config.yml file:

```
did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 101 column 3 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

I tried to unindent everything and indent it again with spaces but the problem persists.
Here is my code:

```
name: "SITENAME | Official Website"
description: "SOME DESCRIPTION"
# url: SOME URL


sass:
  sass_dir: _sass
  style: compressed

author:
  name: "AUTHOR'S NAME"

social-network-links:
  rss: true
  facebook: "FB"
  twitter: "TW"
  linkedin: "LI"

# Select which share links to show in posts
share-links-active:
  twitter: true
  facebook: true
  linkedin: true

# Facebook App ID (for Ads)
# fb_app_id: ""

# Excerpt Word Length
# Truncates the excerpt to the specified number of words on the index page
excerpt_length: 40

# Ruby Date Format
date_format: "%B %-d, %Y"


# --- Comments --- #

# Disqus shortname (NOT userid)
comments:
  provider: "disqus"
  disqus:
    shortname: "SHORTNAME"



# --- Web Statistics Section --- #


google_analytics: "GA"

# Google Tag Manager ID
gtm: "GTM"




# Output options (more information on Jekyll's site)
timezone: "Europe/Berlin"
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
permalink: /:year-:month-:day-:title/
paginate: 5

kramdown:
  input: GFM

# Default YAML values
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: "posts"
    values:
      layout: "post"
      comments: true  # add comments to all blog posts
      social-share: true # add social media sharing buttons to all blog posts
  -
    scope:
      path: "" # all files
    values:
      layout: "page"
      comments: false

# Use tags index page and make tags on each post clickable
link-tags: true

# Exclude these files from production site
exclude:
  - CHANGELOG.md
  - CNAME
  - Gemfile
  - Gemfile.lock
  - LICENSE
  - README.md
  - .jekyll-cache

plugins:
  - jekyll-feed ******THIS IS THE LINE 101*********
  - jekyll-archives
  - jekyll-sitemap
```

I read many threads about this very problem but I can't figure it out. I must say that this is my first config.yml file and I might be missing something easy.
Thanks in advance for your highly appreciated help!

Comment: I checked the code on some yaml linter online and everywhere it says "Valid YAML".

Comment: If the marked line is line 101, you're not showing the complete code. Your code has only 100 lines. As you show it, your file is indeed valid YAML.

Comment: Yes, I just got rid of a couple of comments. Nothing special. 
If the code is valid, what might be the problem? I also deleted the Gemfile.lock and rerun bundle update. This thing is giving me headaches 

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the error happens in this YAML file and not possibly in another one that is included somewhere?

Comment: I do have a couple of yaml files in the _data folder but they were never a problem. I got the error only as soon as I updated the config.file.